# Anyways to access Padrino controller instance variables inside its models?

Tags: ruby, padrino

I wish to access a variable I am setting in controller in the model. Imagine the following:

```
app/controllers/events.rb

...

@language = language_from_query_string
@events = Event.all

render "events"
...


app/models/event.rb

...
def title
  self["title_#{<reference_to_current_controller>.language}".to_sym]
end
...
```

Anyway to do this?

Comment: You could add instance variables to your model (Event.language), or work with generators or helpers. I also do not see why this cannot end up in the view, which has access to language.

Comment: I feel it would make more 'sense' to have this in model than in view. Requesting `event.title` in a view that requires a specific language will return its appropriate language, thought that was a neat approach.

Comment: Or pass the language from your controller/view, so in model `def title(lang=:en) ...`

Comment: Started doing that, and somehow feeling there might be better way to do it.